# iphone dev showing date and time in Push notification

Tags: php, iphone

I have implemented ray wenderlich's tutorials on Apple push notification, now i want to display the date and time on push notification alert, the time that notification has been sent, i know that there is no child property of alert which can hold date and time, so plz. guide me that is there any way to do it (we are sending notification from server side through a php written cms), i want to display date and time at the top right of the notification alert against the sender name, plz. guide thanx and Regards Saad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time when you receive notification may be used to be shown at the right side.
But it is not reliable way, as user can skip any notification. iPhone framework adds icon badge based on value sent in notification.

What you can do is, you can check that value and if it is greater than 0, you can connect to your server by yourself and download the pending notification against that specific user.

Comment: Thanx adil soomro, but that is not what i want, downloading the pending notifications, actually the requirement is only to display the date and time of the current notification, means the time at which the notification has been sent and only want to display it on the notification alert.

Comment: iOS maintains stack of notification along with their arrival time like [this](http://cdn.imore.com/images/stories//2011/10/ios_5_iphone_notification_center_shade-373x560.png) but you cannot add time to AlertView. or you can add time to the message body.